# Custom Object/Class in XCode 4 Interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, interface-builder

Im using Xcode 4. In interface builder of my project, I pulled a custom Object (gold cube) from library. I named its class as MyController and did the same for its label. I saved these settings then.

But I'm not able to write this class to the project's class files. I mean I cannot generate class file from this custom object I pulled from the objects library. I wanted it to inherit from NSObject alone and I want to tie up some outlets.

How do I do this in Xcode 4? Please help. The help documentation regarding this topic is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cubes you see in Interface builder for objects are not there to generate code, they are there to represent objects.

You need to create the class normally and then configure the block to be an object of this class.